# iOS : How to make a simple block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I've a custom view subclass with `UIView`, in it, I've two buttons with an action, now I want to learn something good, and I don't want to implement a delegate to know which button tapped from other class.

I'm showing my custom view with this method,

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[view show];
```

This will show my custom view, with two buttons inside (please assume everything is working fine, I only want to implement block to know which button have been tapped). ^_^

What I've tried for block,

```
- (void) showViewWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(CustomViewType type))completion;
```

and yes, I would able to write like this,

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[view showViewWithCompletionBlock:^(CustomViewType type) {

}];
```

but now here's the trouble, I don't know how to call this block (or how I can return `CustomViewType`) when button tap?

Those two buttons action is like this,

```
- (void) someAction:(UIButton *)sender {
     //sender.tag is a CustomViewType which user choose
}
```

For a note, `CustomViewType` is an `enum` like this,

```
typedef enum {
    CustomViewTypeOption1,
    CustomViewTypeOption2,
}CustomViewType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to deal with blocks using a typedef:

```
typedef void(^CustomViewCompletionBlock)(CustomViewType type);
```

(same thing goes for function pointers).

Now store this block in the custom view, using a private category in the `.m` file:

```
@interface CustomView () {
    CustomViewCompletionBlock _completionBlock;
}
@end

@implementation CustomView
...
@end
```

Do whatever is necessary to display the view and store the completion block:

```
- (void)showViewWithCompletionBlock:(CustomViewCompletionBlock)completion
{
    // Do whatever it takes to "display" the view
    ...
    _completionBlock = completion;
}
```

and then call the completion block as-and-when:

```
- (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender
{
    // Whatever else this method does
    ...
    if (_completionBlock) {
        _completionBlock(CustomViewTypeOption1);
    }
}

- (IBAction)button2Action:(id)sender
{
    // Whatever else this method does
    ...
    if (_completionBlock) {
        _completionBlock(CustomViewTypeOption2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code. when you call compilation . take reference of that compilation and when you want to call that block just use that reference.

in **.h**

```
typedef enum {
CustomViewTypeOption1,
CustomViewTypeOption2,
}CustomViewType;

typedef void(^CustomViewCompletionBlock)(CustomViewType type);

@interface CustomView : UIView
{
    CustomViewCompletionBlock custVTypeBlock;
}
- (void)showViewWithCompletionBlock:(CustomViewCompletionBlock)completion;

@end
```

in **.m**

```
- (void)showViewWithCompletionBlock:(CustomViewCompletionBlock)completion
{
    custVTypeBlock = completion;
    //i'm calling this for sample.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self someAction:nil];
    });
}
- (void) someAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    //sender.tag is a CustomViewType which user choose
    // call your compilation with your enum.
    if(custVTypeBlock)
        custVTypeBlock(0);
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/lavoy/ALActionBlocks

It supports UIControl (UIButton), UIBarButtonItem, and UIGestureRecognizer. It is also supported using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a `block` type is just like calling a C method. If you your block variable name is, say, `myBlock` and if it returns a `CustomType`, then this will work for you:

```
CustomType blockReturnedCustomType = myBlock();
```